# What is the best way to determine/convert the encoding of an external HTML file?

Tags: php, encoding, curl, html-parsing, domdocument

I am parsing HTML from ~100 different domains. I could check what encoding each domain uses & do things that way, but that seems dumb.

Usually the encoding is in the header tags yeah? but not always I gather. so I may need to run some regex? or use some mb_ functions. Or perhaps use cURL? All the examples I've found so far are for XML & now I've got a headache.

Yes also I am using the DOMDocument class to find what I want. And that is all working great. Except for the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [W3C internationalization standards](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php), you should follow these priorities in order to get the encoding of an HTML/XML document:

- `Content-Type` header (from the HTTP response)
- XML or XHTML declaration, e.g.: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`
- `meta` tag with `http-equiv="Content-Type"` (from the HTML header)

In my experience, when all that fails, you can assume encoding is most probably ISO-8859-1 or CP1252. You can decode content using the iconv library, e.g.: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $content)`.

If you use the cURL library to fetch the URLs, you can get the Content Type header with: `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE)`. The other tags can be extracted with an XML/HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a meta tag which any responsible programmer should have included in the `<head>` element.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

You can also choose to reject any html which does not have the charset in the header or in a meta tag.

Comment: yes ok I have found the meta tags using DOMDocument but am having trouble pinning down their actual content. would it be easier to use cURL?